# Java ArrayList Efficiency

Tags: java, performance, arraylist

I am coding a game and have an abstract class known as **GameObject** and three classes extending it (**Player, Wall, and Enemy**).

I have a list defined as so containing all the objects in my game.

```
List<GameObject> objects;
```

When I need to do something with on of the objects, this is how I would do it:

```
public void update() {
    for(GameObject o : objects) {
         if(o instanceof Wall) {
             // do something
         }
         else if(o instanceof Player) {
             // do something
         }

         else if(o instanceof Enemy) {
             // do something
         }
    }
}
```

So as you can see, I have to go through the whole list and check types to find just to find a single object. This seems to me like it's not very efficient. So I then thought about storing the different derived classes in their own lists.

```
private List<Wall> walls;
private List<Enemy> enemies;
private Player player; // only one
```

Would this be more efficient rather than going through the whole list containing everything and checking it's type to decide wether or not to do something? Thanks so much.

Comment: One list or more lists doesn't matter. What you should consider doing is assigning an identifier to each of the objects and store it in a `Map` implementation for easy retrieval.

Comment: I suggest you put the method `doSomething()` in `GameObject` (perhaps `abstract`) then you can just call `o.doSomething()` and let the instance decide what that is. Or maybe `update()`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The normal way to do this would be to use an interface on GameObject.

```
public interface GameObject {
   void update();
}
```

Then just have each object implement GameObject.

```
public class Player implements GameObject {
   public void update() { // update player...
}

public class Wall implements GameObject {
   public void update() { // probably do nothing...
}

public class Enemy implements GameObject {
   public void update() { // update enemy...
}
```

Then your update loop looks like this.

```
public void update() {
    for(GameObject o : objects) {
       o.update();
    }
}
```

I can't guarantee you this is faster, but it probably is.  The compiler will likely be able to optimize a virtual call like this (virtual calls are common in Object Oriented programming, so it's a really good thing for the compiler to know how to optimize), whereas I don't think it's going to be able to optimize an explicit check of the the instance class type nearly as well.